# TF51541: The Node ID is not recognized. When Creating Alerts

Tags: tfs

```
TF51541: The Node ID is not recognized.

i/</<@http://tfsrv10:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/11/_scripts/TFS/TFS.Core.Ajax.min.js?__loc=en-US:4:2402 

m@http://tfsrv10:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/11/_scripts/TFS/TFS.Core.Ajax.min.js?__loc=en-US:4:1703 

i/<@http://tfsrv10:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/11/_scripts/TFS/TFS.Core.Ajax.min.js?__loc=en-US:4:2085 

resolveWith@http://tfsrv10:8080/tfs/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery-1.6.2a.min.js:32:8787 

p@http://tfsrv10:8080/tfs/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery-1.6.2a.min.js:39:36193 

e@http://tfsrv10:8080/tfs/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery-1.6.2a.min.js:39:42692
```

I got this error when creating my alerts on TFS. Anyone had been encounter on this problem?

and can anyone give me solution.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How did you create alerts? Check event log in Event Viewer to see whether there is useful information. Also, try with another team project or in another team project collection to see whether you'll reproduce this issue. And check this blog to see whether it helps you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/13/tf51541-the-node-id-is-not-recognized/

Comment: i use tfs 2012... I create the alert on the collections.. i try several project but still the error pop up..

Comment: Were you able to create alert before? Did you change anything recently? You may try to clean the cache folder on your TFS machine under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache` and `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Web Access\Cache_v11.0` to see whether it helps you.